# Append new shapes to existing shapes within SVG document D3

Tags: d3.js

In D3 I'm used to creating visuals from a blank div.    However I'm trying to get my head around the following.

I have an svg document (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/main/d3%20task1.svg)  which is just 3 rectangles.

What I'm trying to do is append 3 new shapes (circles) to each one of the existing rectangles so that they appear in the centre of each one.

This is where I got to:

```
const svgUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gangrel11/samplefiles/main/d3%20task1.svg"
d3.xml(svgUrl).then(render);


function render(svg) {

  // add svg
  d3.select("body").node().append(svg.documentElement)
  
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

      svg.selectAll("rect")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("x", 20)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("fill",  "red")
      
      }
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/9pwme6s5/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. You are adding another svg element instead of using the existing one.
   My suggestion is changing:

> d3.select("body").append("svg");

to

> d3.select("body").select("svg #layer1");

- notice that I also targeted the `g` element `#layer1` that get transformed.

2. you try to append `rect` element to `rect` element but svg doesn't know how to draw `rect` inside `rect` - this syntax is invalid.
   instead, you can target each element and use his position using the `.each` method and append them after all the existing rects.

code:
function render(svg) {

```
  // add svg
  d3.select("body").node().append(svg.documentElement)
  
  var svg = d3.select("body").select("svg #layer1");

  svg.selectAll("rect")
      .each(function (rect){
         const {x, y} = this.getBoundingClientRect();
         svg.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 20)
            .attr("height", 20)
            .attr("x", this.getAttribute('x'))
            .attr("y", this.getAttribute('y'))
            .attr("fill",  "red");
      
  }); 
}
```